# Instabot Library Like by Hashtag - Error Nothing to like

Tags: python

I am trying to use the instabot library in python to like posts with a certain hashtag.

Whenever I run my code, it says "Nothing to like".

How do I resolve this issue?

```
from instabot import Bot
from time import sleep
import os
import glob

cookie_del = glob.glob("config/*cookie.json")
if cookie_del : os.remove(cookie_del[0])

bot = Bot()

bot.login(username="", password="")

#bot.send_message("yeehaww 2", 'mgarrettblack')

sleep(5)

hashtag = 'electronicmusic'

bot.like_hashtag(hashtag)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you use this module but GitHub https://github.com/ohld/igbot shows that this module is 3 years old - so maybe `Instagram` changed something on page and now code can't work. Or maybe really there is nothing to like in last posts on Instagram